# Decrypting NTAG424 encrypted data fails sporadically with WebCrypto

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, webcrypto-api, subtlecrypto

This is a follow-up question to a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432009/porting-node-js-crypto-code-to-subtlecrypto-webcrypto-fails-with-bad-decrypt/77432512?noredirect=1#comment136528483_77432512), trying to get a working decryption of NDEF URLs from an NXP NTAG424 tag [according to this documentation from NXP (4.4.2.1)](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf).

I've put together an initial WebCrypto code based on @Topaco 's excellent suggestions and the code now succesfuly decodes the `picc` and `enc` from the response and verifies the CMAC.

However, this only works for some payloads, while others still throw a `bad decrypt` error. Iv'e isolated the issue to the decryption of the `enc` static data payload using the derived keys from `sv1`, search for `encDataFull` in the reference code.

The complete implementation follows a reference in Python which is also the backend for the online validation service I refer to later on:
https://github.com/nfc-developer/sdm-backend/blob/master/libsdm/sdm.py

The only difference is the use of `AES-CBC` vs. `AES-ECB`in encoding the `encIVFull`, since `AES-ECB` is not supported by WebCrypto.

[Following this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21048/can-i-simulate-iterated-aes-ecb-with-other-block-cipher-modes), I understood that an `AES-CBC` with an IV of 0s would be equal to `AES-ECB` since only the first block in needed:
`const encIV = Buffer.from(encIVFull).subarray(0, 16)`

Reference for ECB / CBC being the same for IV of zeros:
[CBC Example](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%27CBC/NoPadding%27,%27Hex%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=OTQ1OTJGREU2OUZBMDZFOEUzQjZDQTY4NkEyMjg0MkI)
[ECB Example](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%27ECB/NoPadding%27,%27Hex%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=OTQ1OTJGREU2OUZBMDZFOEUzQjZDQTY4NkEyMjg0MkI)

some payloads work and some fail. This is despite the fact that they all pass verification on an online utility (provided as well)

Working payload ([link to online validation](https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=FDE4AFA99B5C820A2C1BB0F1C792D0EB&enc=94592FDE69FA06E8E3B6CA686A22842B&cmac=C48B89C17A233B2C)):

```js
// https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=FDE4AFA99B5C820A2C1BB0F1C792D0EB&enc=94592FDE69FA06E8E3B6CA686A22842B&cmac=C48B89C17A233B2C
const KEY = '00000000000000000000000000000000'
const PICC = 'FDE4AFA99B5C820A2C1BB0F1C792D0EB'
const ENC = '94592FDE69FA06E8E3B6CA686A22842B'
const CMAC = 'C48B89C17A233B2C'
const CMAC_ARG = 'cmac'
```

returns

```json
{"dataTag":"c7","uid":"04958CAA5C5E80","cnt":"010000","cntInt":1,"cmacPass":true,"data":"78787878787878787878787878787878"}
```

Failing payload ([link to online validation](https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=6107DD7607B179270EAFFCA2F0911940&enc=37C1E399E0948BEA54138F92DDD1E743&cmac=0406016621FC6AC6)):

```js
// https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=6107DD7607B179270EAFFCA2F0911940&enc=37C1E399E0948BEA54138F92DDD1E743&cmac=0406016621FC6AC6
const KEY = '00000000000000000000000000000000'
const PICC = '6107DD7607B179270EAFFCA2F0911940'
const ENC = '37C1E399E0948BEA54138F92DDD1E743'
const CMAC = '0406016621FC6AC6'
const CMAC_ARG = 'cmac'
```

Fails with `bad decrypt`

Another failing payload ([link to online validation](https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=FD91EC264309878BE6345CBE53BADF40&enc=CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac=ECC1E7F6C6C73BF6)):

```js
// https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tagtt?_____TRIAL_VERSION______NOT_FOR_PRODUCTION_____&picc_data=FD91EC264309878BE6345CBE53BADF40&enc=CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac=ECC1E7F6C6C73BF6
const KEY = '00000000000000000000000000000000'
const PICC = 'FD91EC264309878BE6345CBE53BADF40'
const ENC = 'CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962'
const CMAC = 'ECC1E7F6C6C73BF6'
const CMAC_ARG = 'cmac'
```

Would appreciate any further insight on how to make the decryption code more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is an incorrect calculation of the fake padding block in the workaround. You are using the *final* IV as IV instead of the `ENC` ciphertext, which is wrong.

The wrong IV results in a wrong padding block. When decrypting the entire ciphertext, this produces internally random-like bytes at the end of the plaintext, which generally correspond to an incompatible PKCS#7 padding (as a reminder: PKCS#7 is the padding used by WebCrypto and cannot be disabled).
This then triggers a `bad decrypt` (as in your two failure cases). By chance, however, a compatible padding can also result so that no `bad decrypt` is generated (as in your success case), but the data is generally still corrupted by the subsequent processing due to the incorrect (but compatible) padding bytes.

Below is a reminder of how the workaround from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77432512/9014097) works: If you have a plaintext in which the last block `pt_block_last` is *completely* filled, a complete block `pt_padding` consisting of 16 0x10 values is automatically appended when (PKCS#7) padding is enabled, which is encrypted with AES/CBC, whereby `ct_block_last` is used as IV. The latter is the case because CBC applies the ciphertext of the previous block `ct_block_n-1` as IV when encrypting a plaintext block `pt_block_n`, see [CBC flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)).
The workaround does exactly that *explicitly*: When encrypting an *empty* block, the enabled (PKCS#7) padding *automatically* generates a complete padding block consisting of 16 0x10 values. By using the last block of the `ENC` ciphertext (or in the examples the entire `ENC` ciphertext, as this is only 1 block in size) as IV, encryption generates a ciphertext block that contains the encrypted padding and matches the `ENC` ciphertext.
The concatenation of `ENC` and that ciphertext block produces a two-block ciphertext that can be decrypted with WebCrypto when padding is enabled.

---

Test:
Your implementation already generates the *correct* final IV and key for decryption using CMAC. I calculated these two values with your code and use them to test the *fixed* decryption code below:

```js
(async () => {

async function decryptPayload(keyHex, ivHex, encHex) {
    const key = hex2ab(keyHex, 'hex')
    const iv = hex2ab(ivHex, 'hex')
    const enc = hex2ab(encHex, 'hex')
    const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        key,
        {
            name: 'AES-CBC',
            length: 128,
        },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    )
    const encPaddingBlock = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { 
            name: 'AES-CBC', 
            iv: enc.subarray(-16)  // Fix: Apply enc 
        }, 
        cryptoKey, 
        new Uint8Array()
    ) 
    const encPadded = concat(enc, new Uint8Array(encPaddingBlock))
    const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        {
            name: 'AES-CBC',
            iv: iv,
        },
        cryptoKey,
        encPadded
    )
    return decrypted
}

const decoder = new TextDecoder()

// 1
var ENC = '94592FDE69FA06E8E3B6CA686A22842B'
var IV_CMAC = '7b3f3cfc39d3b7ff5868636e38af7c3a'
var KEY_CMAC = '8097d73344d53f963b09e23e03b62336'

var decrypted = await(decryptPayload(KEY_CMAC, IV_CMAC, ENC))
console.log(ab2hex(decrypted))
console.log(decoder.decode(decrypted))

// 2
var ENC = '37C1E399E0948BEA54138F92DDD1E743'
var IV_CMAC = '771aed39fe43c881a9c616fb270be958'
var KEY_CMAC = 'bf3942b425b3b633146182f12d020999'

var decrypted = await(decryptPayload(KEY_CMAC, IV_CMAC, ENC));
console.log(ab2hex(decrypted))
console.log(decoder.decode(decrypted))

// 3
var ENC = 'CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962'
var IV_CMAC = '0ad3eb2717a58332cbc8899bbecbd411'
var KEY_CMAC = '42132d669442ad43e072c8c0c9828a72'

var decrypted = await(decryptPayload(KEY_CMAC, IV_CMAC, ENC));
console.log(ab2hex(decrypted))
console.log(decoder.decode(decrypted))


// helper

function concat(a, b) { 
    var c = new (a.constructor)(a.length + b.length);
    c.set(a, 0);
    c.set(b, a.length);
    return c;
}

function hex2ab(hex){
    return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {return parseInt(h, 16)}));
}

function ab2hex(ab) { 
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(ab), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

})();
```

All three `ENC` ciphertexts are now correctly decrypted.

Comment: thank you once again for your help, and for the detailed explanation on how the IV is tailing in AES-CBC, everything you explained in both this question and the previous one makes sense now, as well as why the workaround works the way it does.

Truely appreciate your help!